# Weird glitch using CardView as a View in custom Toast

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-xml, android-cardview

So i am using custom Toast where i use cardview as layout.

I noticed that in the baseline of the TextView there was appearing a line. what i noticed was that the linearlayout that i used inside the cardView was somehow not getting the background color and interfering with the background color of the cardView. Is this a bug or an erro of mine? or is it just me?

xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/card_view_toast"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/toast_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toast_Text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

java

```
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.a_test, (ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.card_view_toast));

            CardView cardView = (CardView) layout.findViewById(R.id.card_view_toast);
            cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.cinzento));
            cardView.setRadius(20);

            ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_icon);
            image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_cancel);

            TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_Text);
            text.setText("Erro na conexão ao servidor!");

            Toast toast = new Toast(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 50);
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setView(layout);
            toast.show();
```

A screenshot (part of it) of the problem 
[image: it is noticeable the line]

With further Test after all the problem was with the cardView it is giving a weird glitch interfering with the background.

If someone knows a solution plese let me know i really would like so use cardView in the Toas. thats not a really big line but....

Comment: You are setting the background color of the `CardView` not the `LinearLayout`.  If you want to change the background color of the `LinearLayout`, then get a handle on your layout and call `setBackgroundColor` on it.

Comment: but i dont want that, i dont any color on the linear layout!

Comment: I see the problem now, thanks to your edit.  The thin line appears to be a artifact of the Toast itself.

Comment: didnt think that way. yes it looks like it is. removed the linear layout and the line remains there.

Comment: it was because of the cardView...

Comment: Why did you even use cardview in the first place?